# Javascript async/await callback function

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if async/await behave the same in the following two 'super-basic' examples:

```
async function blah1() {
  return await foo.bar().then('Done');
}
```

as this

```
async function blah2() {
  return blah3(foo.bar());
}

async function blah3(fn) {
  return await fn.then('Done');
}
```

or is there some important difference?

- Yes I know 'return await' is redundant but I left it in for this example :)

Comment: I'd start with `then` expecting a function, or, ["If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an "Identity" function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Parameters). Then you wrote "done" once, then "Done". Last but least, there are semantical differences, depending on how you use these functions, but understanding the signatures comes first.

Comment: Yes, these are super basic examples. I don't care what happens inside the then for this example, so I just wrote something quick to demonstrate a then may take place

Comment: I don't think there is a functional difference. Have you observed one?

Comment: Not offhand. Just trying to wrap my head around that scenario and making sure there's not an obvious reason not to do the second option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
async function blah1() {
  return await foo.bar().then('Done');
}

blah1()
```

Calls `foo.bar`, which returns a promise, to which a `then` is added.

The resultant promise is returned.

```js
async function blah2() {
  return blah3(foo.bar());
}

async function blah3(fn) {
  return await fn.then('Done');
}

blah2()
```

Calls `foo.bar`, which returns a promise, which is passed to `blah3`, which adds a `then`.

The resultant promise is returned from `blah3` to `blah2` and thence to the caller.

I'd say no meaningful behavioral difference.